# Which way is better when show tiles image?

Tags: uiimage, tiles, drawrect

I try to show a image in tiles, I think there are some way as below, but I am not sure which one is better, though I can try all ways, but I still hope that I can get info from experience you.

1. use tiles of UIImageView + AnimatedGif
2. use tiles of UIButton in custom style + AnimatedGif
3. use tiles of UIWebView (for gif89a)
4. use UIView and draw tiles of UIImage

Comment: it is ok even no animated gif.I think it is better if I can show animated gif in tiles and all for them in animation.

Comment: people doing tile games use animated gifs for things like water.  Many tile sets use animated gifs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I used first way to do my app.